# Partial group by statements to find the count for multiple instances of a variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm struggling with a fairly simple task. I have the following data and want to find a count of the items in event_list for each visit_high. So it might look like something as follows.

```
Visit_high   visit    event_list
101            1          3
101            2          5
102            1          2
103            1          6
103            2          8
103            3          5
...
```

Visit high is a user id and visit refers to the number of their visit, and event list is the number of actions they took. So user 101 came onto the website two time and took 3 actions during their first and 5 actions during their second visit.

```
> dput(tail(mydf[1:50,c(5,10)], 10))
structure(list(event_list = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 76L, 
36L, 64L, 37L, 14L, 25L), .Label = c("", "100,101,102,115,116", 
"100,101,102,115,116,146", "100,101,102,116", "100,101,102,116,146", 
"100,101,115,116", "100,101,117,118", "100,102,115,116", "100,102,115,116,146", 
"100,102,116", "100,102,116,146", "100,107,115,116", "100,107,116", 
"100,115,116", "100,115,116,146", "100,116", "100,116,146", "100,117", 
"102,115,116", "102,115,116,146", "102,116", "102,116,146", "107,115,116", 
"108,117,118", "115,116", "115,116,146", "116", "116,146", "202", 
"202,120", "205,100,101,109,117,118", "206,115,116", "206,115,116,146", 
"206,116", "206,116,146", "206,214,115,116", "206,214,115,116,146", 
"206,214,116", "206,214,116,146", "206,215,115,116", "206,215,115,116,146", 
"207,102,115,116", "207,102,115,116,146", "207,102,116", "207,102,116,146", 
"207,115,116", "208,100,101,102,115,116", "208,100,101,102,116", 
"208,100,102,115,116", "208,100,115,116", "208,102,109,115,116", 
"208,102,109,116", "208,102,115,116", "208,102,116", "208,109,115,116", 
"208,109,115,116,146", "208,109,116", "208,115,116", "208,116", 
"210,102,108,115,116", "210,102,108,116", "212,102,109,115,116", 
"212,102,109,116", "212,109,115,116", "212,109,116", "212,115,116", 
"214,100,101,102,115,116", "214,100,101,102,115,116,146", "214,100,115,116", 
"214,100,115,116,146", "214,100,116", "214,100,116,146", "214,102,115,116", 
"214,102,115,116,146", "214,102,116", "214,115,116", "214,115,116,146", 
"214,116", "214,116,146", "214,207,102,115,116", "214,221,102,115,116", 
"214,221,102,115,116,146", "215,100,101,102,115,116", "215,100,101,102,115,116,146", 
"215,100,101,102,116", "215,100,101,115,116", "215,100,102,115,116", 
"215,100,102,116", "215,100,115,116", "215,100,115,116,146", 
"215,100,116", "215,102,115,116", "215,102,115,116,146", "215,102,116", 
"215,115,116", "215,115,116,146", "215,116", "215,207,102,115,116", 
"215,207,102,116", "215,221,100,102,115,116", "215,221,100,102,116", 
"215,221,102,115,116", "215,221,102,116", "220,102,115,116", 
"221,100,102,115,116", "221,100,102,115,116,146", "221,100,102,116", 
"221,102,115,116", "221,102,115,116,146", "221,102,116", "226,100,117,119,120", 
"227,102,115,116", "227,102,116", "228,102,115,116", "232,102,115,116", 
"234,102,115,116", "235"), class = "factor"), visid_high = c(2710815361820866560, 
2710815518587167232, 2710815707565725184, 2710815726893081600, 
2710815857889578496, 2710815857889578496, 2710815857889578496, 
2710815883659387904, 2710815902986739712, 2710815950231374336
)), .Names = c("event_list", "visid_high"), row.names = 41:50, class = "data.frame")
```

I have the number of visits for each visitor id, but I'm a little lost on how to differential for each instance of visit_high.

```
event_sum = cbind(mmf$visid_high, mmf$event_list, sapply(strsplit(mmf$event_list, ","), length))
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The sum of  `event_list` for every `Visit_high`? Eg: 8 actions for visitor 101?

Comment: It would also be nice if your examples used consistent spelling, e.g. `visid` vs `visit`. But what we really need is sample output for that very short sample input you provided.

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

```
# dummy data based on your example
du <- data.frame(Visit_high=c(101,101,102,103,103,103),  
                 visit=c(1,2,1,1,2,3), 
                 event_list=c(3,5,2,6,8,5))
# a function to sum all visits for a given visit-high
fu <- function(vh) {
  rows_for_this_user <- which(du$Visit_high==vh)
  events_for_this_user <- sum(du$event_list[rows_for_this_user]) 
  #return a vector with the user id and events count
  c(Visit_high=vh, event_sum=events_for_this_user)
}

data.frame(t(sapply(unique(du$Visit_high), fu)))
```

Sample output.

```
      Visit_high event_sum
1        101         8
2        102         2
3        103        19
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope i got your question right (calling your data **DF**):

```
myfun <- function(row){
  data.frame(event_list = unlist(strsplit(row[1],",")), visid_high = row[2])
}
table(do.call(rbind, apply(DF,1,myfun)))

          visid_high
event_list 2.710815e+18 2.710816e+18
       100            1            4
       101            1            3
       102            1            3
       115            1            9
       116            1            9
       214            0            3
       206            0            2
       109            0            1
       212            0            1
       146            0            1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `sum` by `group`, there are many ways to do.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(du)[, list(event_sum=sum(event_list)), by=Visit_high]
#   Visit_high event_sum
#1:        101         8
#2:        102         2
#3:        103        19
```

Or a `base R` method

```
 aggregate(cbind(event_sum=event_list)~Visit_high, du, FUN=sum)
```

#### data

```
du <- data.frame(Visit_high=c(101,101,102,103,103,103),  
             visit=c(1,2,1,1,2,3), 
             event_list=c(3,5,2,6,8,5))
```